# Changes in cut direction in relativity & consistency of outcomes

Tags: special-relativity

Consider a knife blade angled such that its two ends are separated by a height $h$ and length $L$, that falls onto a sheet of paper at a constant speed $u$, leaving a cut from left to right in the case below.
[image]

Using a Lorentz transformation, we can find what it takes to have some boosted frame in which the cut travels in the opposite direction:
$$cΔt' = γ(cΔt - βΔx) < 0$$
where $ Δt = h/u > 0$ and $Δx = L$;
$$1>β>c\frac{Δt}{Δx} = c/v_{cut}$$
where $v_{cut}$ is the speed at which the end of the cut travels.
So this frame exists for
$$v_{cut} = uL/h > c$$
Now, consider the scenario where this frame indeed exists, but once the cut reaches L/2, the blade is instantaneously vaporised by, say, an extremely powerful laser travelling into the page. In the lab frame, we see half the paper being cut only, but what happens in the boosted frame?

I figured that the boosted observer *must* see the cut travel backwards, and they *must* see the blade vaporised only after the cut is made, so they must observe the cut start in the middle of the paper and then move towards the edge. This seems inconsistent with the shape of the blade however - even if it was distorted by the Lorentz boost to have the "point" of the blade on the opposite end, it feels like it would somehow have to ignore the paper past L/2 to match the lab observer.

Is there any good way of visualising what goes on?

Comment: When you are making a cut, you would be leaving an actual record of things, that you can later come back to check. The angle of the cut is thus necessarily an invariant, although it might look different to different observers. Standard SR can derive everything; the look, the deduced angle, and the transformation of the angles, etc. It is not clear why you want to do it for this particular problem.

Comment: Your analysis is pretty good, but you forgot to account for the relativity of simultaneity, which is a common issue in relativity puzzles. If you say the knife is "instantly" vaporized, you presumably mean it's destroyed all at once. But if that's true in one frame, it isn't true in another frame. In the other reference frame you mention, the knife is gradually vaporized so that the right half is blown up before it reaches the paper, but at that point the left half is still intact and can start cutting.

Comment: In addition, you assumed the knife was straight, i.e. that all the points on its top are at the same vertical position at the same time. Again, that is the kind of statement that, if true in one frame, won't generally be true in another frame due to the relativity of simultaneity. In the other frame you consider, the knife is tilted enough so that it cuts right to left.

Comment: What knzhou said. These are the same issues that arise in the so-called ladder paradox, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/597220/123208