Is simultaneity relative?
The question comes from an earlier post: How can moving observer explain non-simultaneity?
which uses the classic scenario of "passenger on train passes platform when 2 equidistant explosions go off."
Most people here (and textbooks I have seen so far) argue the two observers (Bob and Alice) represent equally valid frames of reference. That's the main idea of relativity, after all.
But there is a key feature which breaks the simple relativity: the doppler-effect
Let Alice detonate the 2 bombs in her (and platform's) rest-frame.
Then ONLY Alice is capable of observing the two explosions without a doppler-induced difference.
In a sense, she represents the true rest-frame of the two simultaneous events.
Bob can never see non-doppler-shifted lights.
Switch it around, so two bombs go off on the train, and the same statement becomes true for Bob. Now only he can see non-doppler shifted lights, and it's a physically detectable situation.
It suggests simultaneity comes with a rest-frame, just like there is rest-mass, rest-length etc.
This could be an easy way to distinguish:

'true' simultaneity - where a rest-frame exists, from which the two events can be observed with no (or equal) doppler-shift

from

'artificial' simultaneity - where no such rest-frame exists. In the frames where the events appear simultaneous they always have opposite (unequal) doppler-shifts caused by the observer's speed relative to the events

Edit: Both Doppler and how it works is completely within mainstream physics. The use of a "rest-frame" for simultaneity works perfectly fine with special relativity, just like rest-length and rest-mass.
I think some people missed that point, and that's why this post got some agitated responses.

Do you understand the spacetime axes rotation in the relativity of simultaneity animation in my answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/597516/123208 ?

Two spacelike separated events determine a spacelike line, which is a coordinate axis for two dimension's worth (and in particular an infinite number of) frames.  Those two dimensions reduce to zero if you choose to assume a 1+1 dimensional spacetime,  which is convenient for pedagogy but not for describing the actual universe.  So yes, if you assume one spatial dimension there is essentially a unique frame in which your two events are simultaneous.  This is of course instantly obvious if you draw a picture, or pause to think for a moment, both of which you seem curiously averse to doing.

@willo Wait, doppler-shift is as real as it gets - not an "artifact of pedagogical choice". Even better, it automatically resolves the cases where one observer claims something happened which is physically impossible in the other (ie. Bob claiming Alice set off 2 equidistant bombs at different times with one optical detonator). Seems like a double win to me. If this site has many posts about using doppler to resolve simultaneity please post links and I'll delete this one.

@pm2ring  I assume you mean the minkowski diagram? yes. It does a great job showing the uniqueness of doppler, since wavelength is the only length not contracted by projecting it onto the simultaneity line. A very strange physical quantity by any measure, and this post is about applying that uniqueness in a useful way.

The radial Doppler factor is central to some treatments of Special Relativity, in particular, Bondi's k-calculus. I have some info at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/598415/123208

I find your previous comment confusing. There's only one animation in my previously linked answer, and it makes no direct reference to Doppler effects.

The Doppler effect has nothing to do with it.

Hmm...I answered the referenced question, mentioned Doppler, and said "Lightning is better than bombs"--because bombs bring out Galilean sensibilities--which has happened here.  In the thought experiment, the explosions are events, points in spacetime, and that has no frame. Once you make a finite explosion, it has a rest frame, so concluding it has a rest frame is no truimf. So, the thought-explosion has a power profile $P(t) = P_0\delta(t)$, which has a white noise power spectral density--which Doppler shifts to: white noise. Maybe the power density changes, you should calculate that.

Relativity gives us the tools to calculate times and properties seen by different observers in different states of motion. But though all frames are valid, giving correct predictions, there may be a "most natural" frame to use for the problem at hand. Likewise, for most physical calcs on Earth, we take $z=0$ to be the local surface of the Earth, and do all our calculations in those coordinates.  For planetary motions, we often take $r=0$ at the center of the Sun. Both are equally valid & could compute all trajectories in all problems. But one is most sensible in different cases.

Notwithstanding the fact that several people have tried to explain simultaneity to you in response to other questions you have posted on the subject, you are stubbornly sticking to your own misunderstanding of the facts. The Doppler effect has nothing to do with the relativity of simultaneity per se. The equations that determine times of events in different reference frames contain neither the frequency nor the wavelength of light, which should prove to you that the effect is independent of both. You can, if you wish, easily conduct a thought experiment in which two events are simultaneous in the frame in which the wavelength of light is shifted by the Doppler effect, and not simultaneous in the frame in which there is no Doppler effect, which should be another proof. I suggest you go back to the answers you have been given, and work on them until you understand.

You actually support my point without realizing it. Of course we can "easily conduct a thought experiment in which two events are simultaneous in the frame in which the wavelength of light is shifted by the Doppler effect, and not simultaneous in the frame in which there is no Doppler effect".  What you describe is "false" simultaneity - see the description just above. Thanks for that. The fact that the age old Bob & Alice observers are NOT equivalent, and that there is an "absolute" frame to determine 'true' simultaneity, is pretty cool. Please share sources on this if you have any.

It is fascinating to observe that, for some users who post on this site and receive answers, the effect seems to reinforce rather than diminish their mental state of "I have understood something that all experts have misunderstood". @MarcoOcram

@MariusLadegårdMeyer indeed! And there seems to be something about relativity, in particular, that triggers that sort of behaviour. I have lost count of the number of people convinced they have 'refuted Einstein'.

@MarcoOcram one can always find apparent contradictions when comparing different 3+1 frames--that's the nature of SR. If you work in Minkowski space, then there are never contradictions nor apparent contradictions (aka: paradoxes).
